# В чём проблемы с функцией SalesTax

Tags: c#

Начал читать C# 7 и .NET Core. Кросс-платформенная разработка для профессионалов. 3-е издание.

В книге есть метод считающий НДС:

```
static decimal SalesTax(decimal amount, string twoLetterRegionCode)
{
    decimal rate = 0.0M;
    switch (twoLetterRegionCode)
    {
        case "CH": // Switzerland
            rate = 0.08M;
            break;
        case "DK": // Denmark
        case "NO": // Norway
            rate = 0.25M;
            break;
        case "GB": // United Kingdom
        case "FR": // France
            rate = 0.2M;
            break;
        case "HU": // Hungary
            rate = 0.27M;
            break;
        case "OR": // Oregon
        case "AK": // Alaska
        case "MT": // Montana
            rate = 0.0M;
            break;
        case "ND": // North Dakota
        case "WI": // Wisconsin
        case "ME": // Maryland
        case "VA": // Virginia
            rate = 0.05M;
            break;
        case "CA": // California
            rate = 0.0825M;
            break;
        default: // most US states
            rate = 0.06M;
            break;
    }
    return amount * rate;
}
```

и вопрос от автора со знаком `!`:

> Можете ли вы представить какие-либо проблемы с функцией SalesTax в том виде, в котором мы ее написали? Что случится, если пользователь введет код региона Великобритании? Как бы вы переписали функцию для улучшения программы в этом аспекте?

Поведайте недогадливому, что с этим методом можно сделать?

Comment: Чтобы отвечать на вопрос "что надо сделать, чтобы решить проблему" - нужно сначала понять проблему. Ответьте на вопрос "Что случится, если пользователь введет код региона Великобритании?" и попробуйте сформулировать проблему этого кода. И вот тогда решая конкретную проблему можно будет показать как улучшить этот код. И уж не знаю, угадаем ли мы проблему, которую пытался донести до нас автор, но вашу проблему точно решим. (И есть мнение, что автор оставивший такую явную подсказку наталкивал вас на совершенно определённую проблему в этом коде)

Comment: если пользователь выберет регион Великобритании, то переменная rate также и останется равна 0.0?

Comment: Предлагаю сделать так. Либо вы формулируете проблему, мы подсказываем как решить, либо вы сдаётесь - и в ответ пойдёт формулировка проблемы, а вы подумаете, как можно её решить. Ну а уж если не сможете и её решить - придёте и зададите новый вопрос.

Comment: Ого как. Нет, переменная не останется равной 0.0 - и похоже ваше непонимание основ языка гораздо больше. Штафной вопрос: перечитайте описание как работает swith. Обратите внимание в вопросе фигурирует не просто британия, а *регион* британии - это прямая подсказка на то, что хотел сказать автор.

Comment: @AK, ок, сейчас буду перечитывать, спасибо

Comment: @AK правильно ли я понимаю, что если мы выберем case без оператора break, то переменной rate будет присвоено значение case с оператором break?

Comment: Мы просто перейдём на выполнение следующего по порядку case. Для британии это будет 0.2 - так же, как и для Франции. Их можно хоть десять подряд case написать, вы ещё увидите не раз такое в коде. Но это вы пока увернулись от неуда за тему, чтобы понять проблему которую автор сформулировал на пять - вам надо сформулировать проблему с *регионом* Британии. Думайте. (Или сдавайтесь, ответ формулирующий проблему я уже написал, но хочу, чтобы вы сами попробовали понять). Если нужен более понятный намёк - попробуйте понять проблему кода в плоскости "есть страны с регионами (США, Британия) и без"

Comment: Не, всё-таки пару слов доскажу про case без break. Если бы в case для британии было бы присвоение допустим 100, но не было бы break - то сначала бы присвоилось одно значение, потом выполнение передалось бы на следующий case - и там бы ещё раз присвоилось 0.2 затерев предыдущее значение (100) и так было постоянно, пока какой-нибудь очередной case не завершился бы break

Comment: @AK спасибо за пояснение про case без break, я думаю что проблема это как разделять в коде страну без регионов и с регионами. А потом уже считать НДС. Верно? Если нет, то я сдаюсь.

Comment: Верно. Подробный ответ - ниже. А вы попробуйте всё-таки решить эту задачу самостоятельно, возможно и получится. (Если нет - можете задать отдельный вопрос) Попробовав сделать самостоятельно вы очень сильно запомните этот трюк - и это вам поможет в работе над реальными проектами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема этого кода в том, что функция нарушает принцип единственной ответственности (SRP). И эта проблема будет спать до того момента, когда вам понадобится этот код расширить (новички в программировании при этом нарушат ещё и Open-Close Principle, то есть поменяют уже написанный ранее код, а не напишут новый код не трогая старый)

Предполагается, что rate зависит от страны, но уже даже для США видно, что в некоторых странах есть регионы - и в них может быть разная ставка.

Представьте себе, что будет с этим кодом, если окажется, что в Британии в разных регионах разная ставка? Ваш switch распухнет, так как внутри будет вложенный switch.
А если в какой-то из стран ставка зависит не от региона, а он расстояния до столицы - вы замучаетесь указывать параметры и т.п.

Для достижения большей поддерживаемости кода нужно разделить ответственности: отдельно определять страну, отдельно возвращать ставку для страны. И вот этот расчёт ставки для страны либо будет константой, либо будет зависеть от региона страны.

На днях на хабре была статья [Непростой принцип единственной ответственности](https://habr.com/en/post/449586/) — в ней как раз очень хорошо объяснены те вещи, о которых идёт речь в вопросе.

> И тут на сцену выходит принцип Open-Close принцип, который прямо
>   говорит, что изменять уже существующий файл было нельзя. Надо было
>   писать код так, чтобы при добавлении новой функциональности нужно было
>   добавить новый файл, а не править уже существующий.

Почитайте, попробуйте самостоятельно переписать код функции SalesTax так, чтобы при последующих доработках кода для определения расчёта ставки для стран с/без учёта региона (США, Британия) не пришлось бы менять существующий код этой функции и код её unit-тестов, а только дописывать новые функции и новые юнит-тесты к ним.

Comment: ок, попробую с этим разобраться. Спасибо!